# OpenCV video capture not loading

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I am trying to load my webcam on my JPanel using Java but its not working. I am new to Java OpenCV. My code is not showing the error just that its not running.

This is my java code:

```
 public void run(){
    synchronized (this) {
        while(true){

            if (webSource.grab()) {
                 System.out.println("err");
                try {
                    webSource = new VideoCapture(0);
                    webSource.retrieve(frame);
                    Graphics g = webcamPanel.getGraphics();
                    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
                    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
                       // System.out.println("ttt");
                        Core.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                new Scalar(0, 255,0));
                    }
                    Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                    Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
                    BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                    if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()-150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null)) {
                        if (runnable == false) {
                            System.out.println("Paused ..... ");
                            this.wait();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is taken from a youtube tutorial. Well his code he use a start and stop button to use the webcam. In my case, I dont want to use button to start my webcam. I want my webcam to run once my program is started. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Tray maybe a `Loaded`-event.

Comment: I'm also really new to java. but I have search it on the internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432708/what-is-form-load-event-handler-in-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815129/what-java-swing-event-can-be-used-to-know-when-application-has-finished-starting are good articles to start whit.

Comment: Try moving webSource = new VideoCapture(0); to before the while(true).